# Trying to access a Fragment from another thread to change TextView text

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, fragment, handler

I am making an app that is using Fragments and wish to change the text in a TextView based on a message received in a client thread communicating with a laptop. The client server communication is no issue as the client thread is receiving the strings just fine.

I can't seem to properly figure out how to access the fragments TextView and alter its text.
Here is how I am currently trying to do so:

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    LivingRoomFragment frag = (LivingRoomFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.LivingRoomFragment);
                    frag.setText("Inside ClientThread right now");
                }
            });
    }
}


public static class LivingRoomFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    TextView temp;

    public LivingRoomFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_room_control_fragment1, container, false);
        temp = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        new Thread(main.new ClientThread(requests)).start();
        return rootView;
    }   

    public void setText(String s){
        temp.setText(s);
    }
}
```

In this case, MainActivity is the activity extending FragmentActivity.

I'm using an emulator and the app always crashing saying there was a null pointer exception at the line using `frag.setText("Inside ClientThread right now")`, which I believe means that the instance of LivingRoomFragment is null. It is to my understanding so far that this is supposed to be executed using a Handler because you cannot access the UI from a thread without using a method like this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are creating new instance of Fragments instead of communicate with current Fragment.

Comment: Okay, how do you go about communicating with the current fragment? I thought the `getFragmentById()` was getting the current fragment but I guess  what its actually doing is using that fragment ID to make a new instance?

Comment: You were correct. Using the ID was making a new instance which was null, by setting a tag when initially committing the LivingRoomFragment to the Fragment manager I am able to later access that fragment using `.getFragmentByTag(tag)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, try

```
MainActivity main = (MainActivity)getActivity;
```

instead of

```
MainActivity main  = new  MainActivity();
```

Comment: Tried this, still `frag.setText()` gives a nullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

okay Toast.
now here is your Solution.

create Broadcast Receiver in your Fragments.
create your action,action is an key which diffrenciat your broadcast.

use below sample code.(you do not have post more code,so it may not ecxatly what you  want okay?)

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    private Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent("my_action");
                intent.putExtra("message", "TEXT_YOU_WANT_TO_SET");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                // LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager
                // .getInstance(context);
                // LivingRoomFragment frag = (LivingRoomFragment)
                // getSupportFragmentManager()
                // .findFragmentById(R.id.LivingRoomFragment);
                // frag.setText("Inside ClientThread right now");
            }
        });
    }
}

public static class LivingRoomFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    TextView temp;
    private MyBroadCastReceiver broadCastReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        broadCastReceiver = new MyBroadCastReceiver();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("my_action"));
    }

    public LivingRoomFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_room_control_fragment1, container, false);
        temp = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        new Thread(main.new ClientThread(requests)).start();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setText(String s) {
        temp.setText(s);
    }

    private class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            // chaneg the TextView text here
            if (intent.getAction() != null
                    && intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("my_action")) {
                temp.setText(intent.getStringExtra("message"));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

good luck.